# Logic code of AMPL about TSPTW

Tags: ampl

I am studing this AMPL code (TSPTW: https://github.com/inter0509/TSPTW).
It is a code to resolve a TSP with Time Window (I hope...)

- rank: binary-matrix (2x2) -> if rank[i,j]==1, then take that arc from "node-i" to "node-j"
- constrain11 : only one arc into the node
- constrain12  only one arc from the node
- constrain13: must select arc to node-0 to node-0
- constrain21: Why is there that piece of code ("+sum{i in V,j in V:i!=j}(c[i,j])*y[i,k-1,j,k];")?
- constrain31/32/33: I have no idea..
- constrain4: you must arrive after sum{j in V}(r[j]*rank[j,k]);
- constarin5: you don't left node before sum{j in V}(d[j]*rank[j,k]);
- "r": hour when you arrive
- "d": hour when you leave the node
- "p": hours you must stop in the node.

Is it correct? I think no...

Comment: Sorry: can you edit my first post? I can't

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit painful trying to interpret uncommented code with uninformative variable names, but I think I've figured it out.

In the previous tsp.mod presented at the same place, there's a binary decision variable x{V,V} which has x[i,j] = 1 if and only if the path goes from node i to node j.

In tsptw.mod there is a binary decision variable rank{V,V}, so we might expect it to work the same way as x{V,V} in the previous model, but it doesn't.

Instead, rank[j,k] = 1 if and only if node j is the k'th city to be visited in the salesman's tour. For instance, if rank[8,3] = rank[5,4] = rank [12,5] = 1, then the third city in the tour is city #8, the fourth is city #5, the fifth is city #12, and so on.

Cities are numbered from 0 to n, so there are actually n+1 cities in this problem.

The decision variable start[j] means "start time of the j'th city in the tour ordering": e.g. if rank[8,3] = 1, then start[3] gives the time at which we start in city #8. (The counting starts at 0 for the start city.)

r and d represent the earliest start time and latest finish time permitted for each city (indexed on the cities' numeric ID, and NOT on their order in the tour). p represents the time required to stay within each city, again indexed on the city's numeric ID.

c[j,k] is the time taken to travel from city j to city k.

y[i,k-1,j,k] equals 1 if the k-1'th city in the tour is city i, and the k'th city is j. (Enforced by constraints 31-33.)

Breaking down the objective function:

```
minimize total_time : start[n]+sum{j in V:j!=0}(c[j,0]*rank[j,n])
+sum{j in V:j!=0} (p[j]*rank[j,n]);
```

- start[n] : this is just the start time for the n'th (last) city in the tour.
- sum{j in V:j!=0}(c[j,0]*rank[j,n]) : rank[j,n] = 1 if and only if city with ID #j is the n'th city in the tour, 0 otherwise. c[j,0] is the time to travel from that city to city #0 (the start). So this gives the travel time from the n'th (last) city to return to where we started.
- sum{j in V:j!=0} (p[j]*rank[j,n]) : this is the time required to spend at the n'th city.

Working through the constraints:

```
subject to constrain11 {j in V}: sum{k in V} rank[j,k]=1;
subject to constrain12 {k in V}: sum{j in V} rank[j,k]=1;
```

Each city must have one and only one rank (position in the tour). For each rank, there must be exactly one city assigned to that rank. (These two are actually redundant, but that doesn't matter.)

```
 subject to constrain13: rank[0,0] = 1;
```

We start at city 0.

```
subject to constrain21 {k in V2}: start[k] >= 
start[k-1] + sum{i in V}(p[i]*rank[i,k-1])
+sum{i in V,j in V:i!=j}(c[i,j])*y[i,k-1,j,k];
```

The time at which we start in the k'th city on our route must be no less than the start time for the previous city, plus the time we needed to spend in that previous city, plus the cost of travelling between the k-1'th and k'th cities.

```
subject to constrain22: start[0] = 0;
```

Start the trip at time zero.

```
subject to constrain31 {i in V,j in V,k in V2}: y[i,k-1,j,k]<=rank[i,k-1];
subject to constrain32 {i in V,j in V,k in V2}: y[i,k-1,j,k]<=rank[j,k];
subject to constrain33 {i in V,j in V,k in V2}: y[i,k-1,j,k]>=rank[i,k-1]+rank[j,k]-1;
```

Collectively, these ensure that y[i,k-1,j,k] is 1 if the k-1'th city visited is i, and the k'th city visited is j, and otherwise it is zero.

Note: although y is indexed on {V,V,V,V2}, most of those indices are actually irrelevant; only the ones where the second index is one less than the fourth index have any significance to the problem.

```
subject to constrain4 {k in V2}: start[k] >= sum{j in V}(r[j]*rank[j,k]);
```

The time at which we start the k'th city of the tour must be greater than or equal to the earliest start time (r) for whatever the k'th city actually is (j such that rank[j,k] = 1).

```
subject to constarin5 {k in V2}: start[k]+sum{j in V}(p[j]*rank[j,k]) 
<= sum{j in V}(d[j]*rank[j,k]);
```

The time at which we start the k'th city, plus the time (p) required for that city, must not exceed the latest finish time (d) for that city.

I haven't gone looking for bugs, so I won't vouch for its correctness, but I think the general approach makes sense under that interpretation.

If you found this answer helpful, please pay it forward by promising always to comment your code and use informative variable names ;-)